# JQuery Form Validation works fine in chrome, firefox and edge But Fails in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate, handlebars.js

I am trying to validate a form using "jquery-validation": "^1.18.0" plugin. This code works fine in chrome, firefox, and edge. But in Internet Explorer 11, this plugin is showing invalid form message even if all the fields have valid data. There is no error in console.

I am using Handlbar JS.

My HTML code is

```
<div class="lets-connect-standalone" data-component-lets-connect-standalone>
<form action="" method="post" name="connectForm" class="connectForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="paginatedform">
            <div class="formpage">
                <div class="form-control formfield" data-component-form-control>
                    <input  type="text" name="firstName" class="firstName" placeholder="" required="true" />
                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <span class="icon icon-Error-Icon error-exclamation"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="continue-btn">
                <button class="nextbutton btn-animation-fixed-border" type="button">CONTINUE</button></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My Js code is

```
class LetsConnectStandalone {
constructor(el){
    let validator = $(".connectForm",el).validate({
        errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
            if(element.is(":radio")){
                console.log("element error radio : ",element);
                $('<br/>',el).insertAfter(element);
                label.addClass('arrow radio-error-text');
                label.appendTo( element.parents('.container') );
            }else{ 
                if(element.is("select")){
                    label.addClass('arrow select-error-text');
                }else{
                    if(element.is("textarea")){
                        label.addClass('arrow textarea-error-text');   
                    }else{
                        label.addClass('arrow error-text');
                    }
                }
                label.insertAfter( element );
            }                                   
        },        
        wrapper: 'span',
        ignore: ":hidden:not(.recaptchaField)",
        rules: {
            "g-recaptcha-response": "required"
        },
        submitHandler:function(form){
            if(!ispagevalid(form)){
                return;
            }else{ 
                let params = $(form).serialize();
                console.log("Form is submitted : ",params);        
            }
        },
        error: function(event){
            try{grecaptcha.reset();}catch(e){}
        }
    });
    let ispagevalid = function(formpage){
        let valid = true;
        $('input, select, radio, textarea', formpage).each(function(i, v){
            valid = validator.element(v) && valid;
        });
        if(!valid){
            try{grecaptcha.reset();}catch(e){}
        }
        return valid;
    }
    //Continue/Next button behavior
    $("button.nextbutton",el).click(function(event){
        let button = $(this);
        let currentPage = $(button,el).parent(".continue-btn").parent(".formpage");
        if(ispagevalid(currentPage)){
            let nextPage = $(currentPage).next();
            currentPage.hide();
            nextPage.show();
        }else{
        }
    });
}}export {LetsConnectStandalone};
```

Screenshot of chrome

[image]

Screenshot of Internet Explorer

[image]

Comment: And have you done any troubleshooting?  What version of Explorer?  What are the console errors?  Have you inspected the DOM?  Have you tried it without handlebars.js?

Comment: Please do not use the Code Snippet feature if you don't know how to make it run on this page.

Comment: Also please click edit, then the `[<>]` button and add relevant libraries and CSS @Sparky - indeed use the snippet editor, just make sure it is a [mcve]

Comment: Also what is this? If you have jQuery, then `let dom2=dom.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;` should not be necessary

Comment: The whole thing makes no sense... you cannot have non-empty fields and validation errors at the same time.

Comment: Horrific mix of jQuery and DOM. `$('.talkabout-cnt',dom2).children()[1].innerHTML==errorLable` Please have a developer look at this code

Comment: I actually do not even see any sign of handlebars here.

Comment: I would also suggest that you condense the code down into the smallest amount possible that still reproduces the issue.  You don't need to be showing us all that Google Captcha JavaScript code.  Just way too much fluff than I care to get into.

Comment: Question is updated to include minimal version of error code

Comment: Any console errors? And is the issue that Diji gives error even though it should not?

Comment: no console error. Yeah, fields are not validated properly in IE - 11. When I click 'Continue' button, this filed show error even if it has valid data in IE -11

Comment: Just noticed jQuery Validate version 1.18.0 ... either that is not the same jQuery Validate plugin or you're using pre-release software.  The latest official version is still 1.17.0.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Validation [1.8.0 released on 2018-09-09](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.18.0) introduced a regression on IE11.

See https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/2211

The issue was fixed in [release 1.9.0](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.19.0) on 2018-11-28

Answer (score -1):

Everything works fine once I downgraded jquery-validation plugin to 1.17.0. I was using jquery 3.3.1.

Comment: ***Downgraded*** to jQuery Validate to version 1.17.0?  Since 1.17.0 is the latest official version, it's the one you should have been using all along.

Comment: I don't know how , but when I done npm install, I got 1.18.0